# OpenCL / OpenGL and osx crashes

Tags: opengl, kernel, opencl, osx-elcapitan, openframeworks

I've been working on an opencl octree ray caster which is written in openframeworks. It takes point clouds of 5-10m points, builds an octree, passes the octree to the kernel and then runs about 200k raycasts to find point interceptions.

The code is working well enough, with results being rendered through vbo objects. See [here](https://vimeo.com/163826612) and [here](https://vimeo.com/163915561) for a couple of clips (still perfecting the intersection checks).

The problem is, I have been having a whole series of mac black screen moments lately. (I'm on a late 2013 mac pro with a recent el-cap update) I'm pretty sure that the black screens are some form of kernel crash or overload (?). They happen both occasionally when the app is running and also even when OF has been shut down and I've moved on to other work afterwards. Regularly enough to make working a nightmare...

I'm fairly green with opencl and the like but I think that my basic kernel code is sound. I am also including cleanup functions in the c++ on exit. Are there any other simple issues/safeguards that I may be unaware of that I need to be sure to include/I could try in my app?

It may be I need to include more information, happy to update in response to questions.

In hope
S

update:
here's a system report from the latest shut down; happened after a restart after a crash after running the app. I have totally zero clue:

```
Anonymous UUID:       1B68061F-68FC-BED2-559B-C8457A01380E

 Sun Apr 24 16:03:12 2016

*** Panic Report ***
 panic(cpu 6 caller 0xffffff7f92b72bd5): "GPU Panic: [<None>] 3 0 a0 d9 9 8 0 3 : NVRM[0/1:0:0]: Read Error 0x00000100: CFG 0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0xffffffff, BAR0 0x103e00000 0xffffff92013c9000 0x0e7150a2, D0, P3/4\n"@/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleGraphicsControl/AppleGraphicsControl-3.12.6/src/AppleMuxControl/kext/GPUPanic.cpp:127
 Backtrace (CPU 6), Frame : Return Address
 0xffffff91fd61ae30 : 0xffffff800fadab12 
 0xffffff91fd61aeb0 : 0xffffff7f92b72bd5 
 0xffffff91fd61af90 : 0xffffff7f908241e0 
 0xffffff91fd61b050 : 0xffffff7f908f1ef4 
 0xffffff91fd61b090 : 0xffffff7f908f1f5f 
 0xffffff91fd61b110 : 0xffffff7f90b297a8 
 0xffffff91fd61b1b0 : 0xffffff7f90b413d2 
 0xffffff91fd61b1f0 : 0xffffff7f9096943a 
 0xffffff91fd61b220 : 0xffffff7f909693c5 
 0xffffff91fd61b250 : 0xffffff7f90a770c9 
 0xffffff91fd61b280 : 0xffffff7f90a78ea4 
 0xffffff91fd61b310 : 0xffffff7f90a79306 
 0xffffff91fd61b370 : 0xffffff7f90839636 
 0xffffff91fd61b3c0 : 0xffffff7f90a7d828 
 0xffffff91fd61b530 : 0xffffff7f90a7dc3a 
 0xffffff91fd61b5c0 : 0xffffff7f90928186 
 0xffffff91fd61b720 : 0xffffff7f90926ddf 
 0xffffff91fd61b760 : 0xffffff7f90936ffa 
 0xffffff91fd61b7c0 : 0xffffff7f90931337 
 0xffffff91fd61b7e0 : 0xffffff7f908eed6e 
 0xffffff91fd61b820 : 0xffffff7f908ede6f 
 0xffffff91fd61b890 : 0xffffff7f90827441 
 0xffffff91fd61b8b0 : 0xffffff7f90827ddb 
 0xffffff91fd61baa0 : 0xffffff7f9082815a 
 0xffffff91fd61bb40 : 0xffffff7f907d45c0 
 0xffffff91fd61bbc0 : 0xffffff7f907d3df2 
 0xffffff91fd61bc20 : 0xffffff7f907d574e 
 0xffffff91fd61bc60 : 0xffffff7f907864f5 
 0xffffff91fd61bcf0 : 0xffffff7f9077e10b 
 0xffffff91fd61bd20 : 0xffffff80100946b1 
 0xffffff91fd61bd70 : 0xffffff80100de2f9 
 0xffffff91fd61bde0 : 0xffffff800fb977a1 
 0xffffff91fd61be30 : 0xffffff800fadf283 
 0xffffff91fd61be60 : 0xffffff800fac28b8 
 0xffffff91fd61bea0 : 0xffffff800fad2665 
 0xffffff91fd61bf10 : 0xffffff800fbb8bda 
 0xffffff91fd61bfb0 : 0xffffff800fbeca96 
       Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
     com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f90774000->0xffffff7f907aefff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9032c000
     com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl(3.12.6)[44D361A1-4938-3AA5-9F73-9C909B66214B]@0xffffff7f92b64000->0xffffff7f92b77fff
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.12.6)[1654475C-9A4B-386C-AFA8-0A530194A2F9]@0xffffff7f92b5c000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[5D7574C3-8E90-3873-BAEB-D979FC215A7D]@0xffffff7f90f7f000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9032c000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f90774000
        dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert(1.1.0)[C49819CE-729A-36B2-9AC1-744A43DC236F]@0xffffff7f92b5f000
     com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1)[8649777A-3EED-3F2F-8B12-FBC5517F62E6]@0xffffff7f907d2000->0xffffff7f90a4bfff
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9032c000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport(2.4.1)[1114B99F-E439-329E-876D-1FEC4CF45DF6]@0xffffff7f907bb000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[172C2960-EDF5-382D-80A5-C13E97D74880]@0xffffff7f90774000
        dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.12.6)[F211EB28-182A-34BB-A610-87667618F925]@0xffffff7f907cb000
     com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal(10.1)[EB8A5980-AB59-368A-8244-60A00C7A933C]@0xffffff7f90a57000->0xffffff7f90c05fff
        dependency: com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman(10.1.0)[8649777A-3EED-3F2F-8B12-FBC5517F62E6]@0xffffff7f907d2000
        dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[4FE41F9B-2849-322A-BBF8-A94816C003D6]@0xffffff7f9032c000

 BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WindowServer

 Mac OS version:
 15E65

 Kernel version:
 Darwin Kernel Version 15.4.0: Fri Feb 26 22:08:05 PST 2016; root:xnu-3248.40.184~3/RELEASE_X86_64
 Kernel UUID: 4E7B4496-0B81-34E9-97AF-F316103B0839
 Kernel slide:     0x000000000f800000
 Kernel text base: 0xffffff800fa00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff800f900000
 System model name: MacBookPro10,1 (Mac-C3EC7CD22292981F)

 System uptime in nanoseconds: 8583589115
 last loaded kext at 7720294530: com.apple.driver.AGPM  110.21.18 (addr 0xffffff7f92b3c000, size 122880)
 loaded kexts:
 net.telestream.driver.TelestreamAudio  1.0.5
 com.logmein.driver.LogMeInSoundDriver  4.1.63f33
 com.apple.driver.AGPM  110.21.18
 com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler  2.6.0d0
 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim   1.0.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyHIDDriver   124
 com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog  1
 com.apple.driver.AppleMikeyDriver  274.7
 com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC 1.70
 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver  274.7
 com.apple.driver.pmtelemetry   1
 com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleHDA  274.7
 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager   4.4.4f4
 com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient   3.6.1
 com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X  7.0.0
 com.apple.GeForce  10.1.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelHD4000Graphics  10.1.4
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU   208
 com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin   1.0.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleHV   1
 com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver   4.1.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight    170.8.9
 com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport    4.4.4f4
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMCPDRC  1.0.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleLPC  3.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP    3.0.8
 com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl   3.12.6
 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking    4.0.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl  1.2.13
 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelFramebufferCapri    10.1.4
 com.apple.nvidia.NVDAStartup   10.1.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCButtons 245.4
 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU  4.4.4f4
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyEventDriver  245.4
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBTCKeyboard    245.4
 com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck   517.20.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
 com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
 com.apple.BootCache    38
 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4331  800.20.24
 com.apple.driver.AppleSDXC 1.7.0
 com.apple.iokit.AppleBCM5701Ethernet   10.2.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage 2.8.5
 com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360  1040.1.1a6
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCIPCI   1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort 3.1.8
 com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons  4.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleRTC  2.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleHPET 1.8
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS   2.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC   4.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC 1.7
 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagementClient    218.0.0
 com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall  163
 com.apple.security.quarantine  3
 com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet 8
 com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCPUPowerManagement  218.0.0
 com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib    274.7
 com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib   525
 com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily 11
 com.apple.driver.CoreCaptureResponder  1
 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAGK100Hal   10.1.0
 com.apple.nvidia.driver.NVDAResman 10.1.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOSurface  108.2.1
 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy    1.0.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport  4.4.4f4
 com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily  4.4.4f4
 com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController    274.7
 com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily    274.7
 com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily  204.3
 com.apple.vecLib.kext  1.2.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink   4.1.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter  4.1.3
 com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert  1.1.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl  3.12.6
 com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin 1.0.0
 com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily    6.0.0d7
 com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily   1.0.0
 com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport  2.4.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMC  3.1.9
 com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController  1.0.14d1
 com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2   205.3
 com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl   3.12.6
 com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily   2.4.1
 com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily  3.7.7
 com.apple.driver.usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice    1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMultitouch    250.5
 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver 900.4.1
 com.apple.driver.usb.cdc   5.0.0
 com.apple.driver.usb.networking    5.0.0
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHostCompositeDevice   1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBHub   1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.CoreStorage   517.20.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter   4.1.3
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily   4.1.3
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.0.2
 com.apple.driver.AppleXsanScheme   3
 com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI   4.0.4
 com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily    6.0.2
 com.apple.iokit.IOEthernetAVBController    1.0.3b3
 com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family  1110.26
 com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient 1.0.1b8
 com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily 3.2
 com.apple.driver.corecapture   1.0.4
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub  900.4.1
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBEHCI  1.0.1
 com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily   2.8.1
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCIPCI   1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.usb.AppleUSBXHCI  1.0.1
 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily    900.4.1
 com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHostFamily    1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHostMergeProperties   1.0.1
 com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM 2.0
 com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime   2.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily    2.0.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily  1.1
 com.apple.security.sandbox 300.0
 com.apple.kext.AppleMatch  1.0.0d1
 com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore 2
 com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
 com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager    1.0
 com.apple.driver.DiskImages    417.2
 com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily    2.1
 com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily 31
 com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore  28.30
 com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform 4.0
 com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily    2.9
 com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily   1.4
 com.apple.kec.pthread  1
 com.apple.kec.corecrypto   1.0
 com.apple.kec.Libm 1
 Model: MacBookPro10,1, BootROM MBP101.00EE.B0A, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2.7 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.3f36
 Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 4000, Intel HD Graphics 4000, Built-In
 Graphics: NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M, PCIe, 1024 MB
 Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD,      0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
 Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D5434314753364D465238432D50422020
 AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0xEF), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.21.95.175.1a6)
 Bluetooth: Version 4.4.4f4 17685, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
 Network Service: AirPort, AirPort, en0
 Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SD512E, 500.28 GB
 USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
 USB Device: Hub
 USB Device: FaceTime HD Camera (Built-in)
 USB Device: USB 2.0 Bus
 USB Device: Hub
 USB Device: Hub
 USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad
 USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub
 USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
 USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus
 Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 23.4
```

Comment: You must design OpenCL kernels to execute on the order of milliseconds or at least less than a second. Anything longer and your graphics system hangs. On Windows after 8 seconds the OS will terminate your work and reset the GPU.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Yes, it executes at about 0.1s for 100k rays. The crash seems to happen after the kernel app has been closed down often too.

Comment: For instance, just now; rebooted and started using sketchup and then boom, black screen of doom, randomly. Could the opencl kernel be filling up the gpu and not clearing on the app exit? Between reboots too? :-/

Answer (score 0):

So after much checking, there isn't anything wrong with my opencl code.

The issue appears to be that the GPU has some kind of heat throttling going on; if it hits 55 degrees Celsius it shuts down, boom. Go Apple.

By downloading smcFanControl and gfxCardStatus, turning the fans to full and keeping an eye on the temperature I've got the panics down to a bearable/manageable occurance.

Not great but maybe I need a better laptop.